@typescript-eslint/parser version 8 throws error for index signatures from enum
Upgrading the @typescript-eslint/parser from 7 to version 8.5 leads to the error
error  'scope' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
for codes like
export type AuthorizationPayload = {
  [scope in Scope]?: Permission[]
}

export enum Scope {
  Serlo = 'serlo.org',
...
}

Here is the error in our CI.
Here the eslint file
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": ["tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "react"],
  "rules": {
    // eslint
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-console": "error",

    // @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "types": {
          "String": {
            "message": "Use string instead",
            "fixWith": "string"
          },
          "Boolean": {
            "message": "Use boolean instead",
            "fixWith": "boolean"
          },
          "Number": {
            "message": "Use number instead",
            "fixWith": "number"
          },
          "Symbol": {
            "message": "Use symbol instead",
            "fixWith": "symbol"
          },
          "Object": {
            "message": "Use object instead",
            "fixWith": "object"
          },
          "Function": {
            "message": "The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.\nIt provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.\nIt also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.\nIf you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape."
          },
          "{}": {
            "message": "`{}` actually means \"any non-nullish value\".\n- If you want a type meaning \"any object\", you probably want `object` instead.\n- If you want a type meaning \"any value\", you probably want `unknown` instead.\n- If you want a type meaning \"empty object\", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead."
          }
        },
        "extendDefaults": false
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": ["error", "interface"],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-extraneous-class": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-parameter-properties": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": [
      "error",
      {
        "classes": false,
        "functions": false,
        "typedefs": false
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-constructor": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-ts-expect-error": "error",

    // eslint-plugin-import
    "import/export": "error",
    "import/extensions": ["error", "never", { "json": "always" }],
    "import/first": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/no-absolute-path": "error",
    "import/no-commonjs": "error",
    "import/no-cycle": "error",
    "import/no-default-export": "error",
    "import/no-deprecated": "error",
    "import/no-internal-modules": [
      "error",
      {
        "allow": [
          "@pact-foundation/pact/src/dsl/matchers",
          "msw/node",
          "msw/lib/**",
          "mysql2/promise",
          "io-ts/lib/*",
          "io-ts-types/lib/*",
          "fp-ts/lib/*",
          "ts-jest/utils",
          "@apollo/server/plugin/disabled",
          "@apollo/server/express4"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "import/no-mutable-exports": "error",
    "import/no-self-import": "error",
    "import/no-unassigned-import": "error",
    "import/no-useless-path-segments": [
      "error",
      {
        "noUselessIndex": true
      }
    ],
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc"
        },
        "groups": [
          ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
          ["parent", "sibling", "index", "unknown"]
        ],
        "newlines-between": "always"
      }
    ],

    // eslint-plugin-react
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": "error",
    "react/jsx-curly-brace-presence": "error",
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "pragma": "h",
      "version": "16.8"
    }
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "__fixtures__/**/*",
        "__tests-pacts__/**/*",
        "__tests__/**/*",
        "jest.setup.ts",
        "jest.setup-pacts.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Of course, I could put a '_${}' before each such cases, but there is a lot of these in the code and I actually think typescript-eslint shouldn't throw an error here (I mean it is a regression in the version 8). Is there an elegant solution?
How can I ignore such cases?
And could anyone explain me the reasoning behind this new way of handling dynamic keys of object, i.e. index signatures from enum?

Did you check their changelog for breaking changes? 7.0.0 to 8.5.0 is a big jump

I checked you CI build.
Updating @typescript-eslint/parser but not @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin is probably not very useful. Especially with this big version jump.
The presented code itself works in the ts-eslint playground.

thanks, it solved upgrading both at the same time solved it

You could mark my answer as accepted answer.
